# Is using DeclareMathOperator for functions the right thing to do?

Tags: amsmath, math-operators

I'm wondering if I use the `\DeclareMathOperator` for the wrong things.

For example I have a cost function `cost(x,y)` which takes two arguments. I would declare it as `\DeclareMathOperator*{\cost}{cost}` and use it later with `$\cost(x,y) = ...$`.

If this is correct, why do I never see the function `f(...)` typeset in roman? If it's not correct when should the `\DeclareMathOperator*` be used instead?

Comment: I would say that `f` is a "variable function", with no pre-defined meaning, contrary to `log`, `abs`, `dom`, `tr`, `sgn`, etc. But the question is worth asking, to me.

Comment: You don't want the `*`, for such an operator. The generic “f” for functions is a variable, so it surely is in italics.

Comment: There are two reasons or criteria for using `\DeclareMathOperator` (and its "starred" version, `\DeclareMathOperator*`): First, you wish to typeset its name in roman rather than italic -- as is customary with `sin`, `cos`, `exp`, `log`, `det`, etc. Second, you may wish to position the operator's argument either immediately below or in a subscript position to the right of the function name, as in `\max_{x}f(x)`. "Generic" function names, such as *f* and *g*, probably don't satisfy either criterion.

Comment: @egreg @Clément So because in my case `cost` is not a variable function you would say I can use the `\DeclareMathOperator` command?

Comment: @user2653422 You should: it represents *that* function, just like “log” for the logarithm and “sin” for the sine.